# cannot load such file -- coffee_script on Rails 6

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

currently I am working on Rails 6, and I met

> "cannot load such file -- coffee_script"

I took a look in Gemfile and there is no gem `'coffee-rails'`
and I have tried  `$ rails tmp:cache:clear`  to clear cache and restart server.
but I still get the same error.

```html
!!!
%html
  %head
    %meta{content: "text/html; charset=UTF-8", "http-equiv": "Content-Type"}/
    %title Myapp
    = csrf_meta_tags
    = csp_meta_tag
    = stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload'
    = javascript_include_tag 'application'
  %body
    = render 'layouts/notifications'
    = yield
```

```
enter code here
application.js

//= require jquery
//= require rails-ujs
//= require_tree .
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzoMI.png)

Answer (score 0):

To be able to answer your question better, you should probably also post your `application.js` file – because this is the thing that triggers the error.

Generally, two things:

- Rails doesn't really encourage using CoffeeScript anymore. That doesn't mean that you can't use it – just that it has fallen out of favor and people tend to use other facilities these days (eg. Babel).
- In order to make CoffeeScript work in Rails, you need to have the `coffee-rails` gem in your `Gemfile`. If it's not there, you need to add it and then it should usually work out-of-the-box.

Comment: thanks for the advice.  and I just add application.js.  to just make sure that I am not going to use CoffeeScript so i have no any CoffeeScript files. i just want to use js files for JavaScript.